What is the difference between transaction revert and status:0?
After running
transaction = abi_func(**func_args).build_transaction({
            'chainId': 1337,
            'gas': 200000,
            'gasPrice': w3.eth.gas_price,
            'nonce': w3.eth.get_transaction_count(tx_sender),
            # 'maxFeePerGas': 50000000000,
        })

signed_txn = w3.eth.account.sign_transaction(transaction, private_key=private_key)
tx_hash = w3.eth.send_raw_transaction(signed_txn.rawTransaction)
transaction_receipt = w3.eth.wait_for_transaction_receipt(tx_hash)

When I add 'maxFeePerGas':50000000000 to build_transaction(), it will raise transaction revert.
If without this, the status in receipt of transactions are mostly 0.
What is the difference between these two?
besides, I get transaction trace through debug_traceTransaction, what does the 'op:STOP' in trace mean?

They both mean that the transaction fails. But there are slight differences in transaction revert and status: 0 how they are labelled.
transaction revert
transaction revert happends when a tx fails during its execution. This can have couple of reasons, f.e. often because insufficient gas was supplied, contract rules were violated, etc. , so it indicates the transaction attempted execution but failed to apply any changes to the state. You may see the status 0x0.
status: 0
status: 0 also means that the transaction failed, but the tx was submitted, but did not successfully execute and the intended changes did not happen -  so it states that the transaction was not successful. Error shows as 0 in the transaction receipt.
In your case:
When you include a maxFeePerGas that is way lower than the current market rate, it can lead to the transaction being rejected, the transaction will revert.
If you remove the maxFeePerGas, the transaction is built with the current gas price. If the gas price is sufficient, the transaction may still fail (leading to status 0), but it won't revert because of low fees.
debug_traceTransaction
Regarding debug_traceTransaction: If you see op:STOP, it means that the EVM has reached a point where it completed its operations successfully or reached an end, but it does not necessarily imply success of the tx itself (it could have reached a STOP due to a revert).
